# Doctrine query builder with in expression

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I try to get all users who has a mail in three different properties with in expression

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->where(':email in (i.firstMail,i.secondtMail,i.thirdtMail)');
```

I got this error in getResult

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 61: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'i'
```

Answer (score 0):

In DQL the lexer expects the contents of the IN() function to either be a subselect or a comma separated list of literals.  https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/f92c3dba324923729373b1fdfc324b77e5cc5900/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php#L3102

To get what you want you must either create multiple where conditions or aggregate the other 3 fields in a subselect.

Additionally, I recommend using the expression builder for complex expressions: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Comment: strange, it works with sql, for example
select * from user where '"test@gmail.com" in (firstMail,secondMail)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->andWhere('i.firstMail LIKE :email OR i.secondtMail LIKE :email OR i.thirdtMail LIKE :email')
   ->setParameter('email', '%'. $email. '%');
```